# Reading lines from a file in random order

Tags: file, clojure, shuffle, lazy

I originally wrote this as [an answer to a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33507318/5044950), but it turned out so nicely that I decided to post it here to see if I can make it even better.

```clj
(defn char-seq
  "Returns a lazy sequence of characters from rdr. rdr must implement
  java.io.Reader."
  [rdr]
  (let [c (.read rdr)]
    (if-not (neg? c)
      (cons (char c) (lazy-seq (char-seq rdr))))))

(defn line-offsets
  "Returns a lazy sequence of offsets of all lines in s."
  [s]
  (if (seq s)
    (->> (partition-all 3 1 s)
         (map-indexed
          (fn [i [a b c]]
            (cond
              (= b \newline) (if c (+ 2 i))
              (= a \return) (if b (inc i)))))
         (filter identity)
         (cons 0))))

(defn ordered-line-seq
  "Returns the lines of text from raf at each offset in offsets as a lazy
  sequence of strings. raf must implement java.io.RandomAccessFile."
  [raf offsets]
  (map (fn [i]
         (.seek raf i)
         (.readLine raf))
       offsets))
```

Example usage:

```clj
(let [filename "data.txt"
      offsets (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader filename)]
                (shuffle (line-offsets (char-seq rdr))))]
  (with-open [raf (java.io.RandomAccessFile. filename "r")]
    (run! println (ordered-line-seq raf offsets))))
```

I'm interested in any way to improve this code, but here are some specific things I'm looking for:

- Since `RandomAccessFile` obviously uses byte offsets, and `line-offsets` returns character offsets, this code won't work for Unicode files. Is there a way to fix that problem without adding a lot of complexity?
- Are `a`, `b`, and `c` good names for the parameters of the anonymous function in `line-offsets`?
- What exactly are the guidelines for parameter ordering in named functions like `ordered-line-seq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

- You're reading bytes.  Fortunately, the only three line ending
  conventions all involve Newline and Return, both a single byte.
  There's nothing more to it.  So if you stay with an *encoding* using
  single bytes for (most of) their characters, such as UTF-8, there will
  be no problem.  For other Unicode encodings you'd have to read more
  than one byte per character and also do some decoding.

  Frankly even without encodings this is a hairy topic,
  c.f. [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) on Wikipedia.
  Though `line-offsets` uses the same convention as `readLine`, so I
  guess that's just FYI.
- I'd at least not use short/one-letter variable names for function
  parameters, because they also serve as documentation.  E.g. `r`
  doesn't tell the reader anything, `rdr` is barely english, but
  `reader` is clear and doesn't cost that much more in terms of
  characters.  Same with `s` and `sequence`.  For `a`, `b`, `c` in
  `line-offsets` I'd even say that `c1` to `c3` would be more helpful.
- It'd be best to orient yourself at standard functions.  It's probably
  better to have the most important "subject" first, then subsequently
  the rest unless there's a good reason not to.  Parameters at the ends
  can also very easily be curried, maybe that's another hint to think
  about it.

Other than that, yeah, looks good.  I don't quite see why the laziness
is necessary, since it's calling `shuffle` anyway, but perhaps it's
useful in some situations?

Comment: Yeah, the only function that needs to be lazy here is `ordered-line-seq`, but I figured that there's no reason for the other two functions *not* to be lazy, so I made them lazy anyway. `c1` to `c3` do seem like better names; however, would you say that consistency with [`line-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq) is a good enough reason for the name of the `rdr` parameter in `char-seq`?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion really. I'm not overly fond of the standard library naming, so my post is coloured by that.

Comment: I can certainly understand that; I do agree that `rdr` is not very readable here. Anyway, thanks for the comments! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Actually assert the preconditions**

You say in your documentation:

```clj
rdr must implement
  java.io.Reader.
```

Still, if I pass in a `rdr` that has not `java.io.Reader` implemented, I am going to get a weird error. I would provide a use friendly error message. (Pseudocode):

```clj
(defn char-seq
  "Returns a lazy sequence of characters from rdr. rdr must implement
  java.io.Reader."
  [rdr]
  (when (not (implements java.io.Reader rdr))
    raise "rdr must implement java.io.Reader")
  ; ... the same
```

**`rdr`?**

This name is hard to understand, remember that your function parameters names are part of the documentation and should be as clear as possible, when in doubt err on the side of verbosity.

Comment: All good advice, but my goal was for `char-seq` to be as similar as possible to [`line-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq), which shares that exact parameter name. Also, "must implement" in the `line-seq` docstring really just means "must support the same method signatures", so I'm using that meaning here as well; that's why [`line-seq` doesn't assert its precondition](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2954) either.